# PHP GD Image Corruption On imagecopy()

Tags: php, image, gd, corrupt

I'm experiencing some weirdness with PHP 5.3.3, i'm trying to add a watermark to an image.

```
$body = @imagecreatefromstring($image_data['body']);
imagejpeg($body, null, 85);
```

returns in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJjDi.jpg

```
$body   = @imagecreatefromstring($image_data['body']);
$logo   = @imagecreatefrompng(APP_ROOT . self::WATERMARK_PATH);

$body_width     = (int) @imagesx($body);
$body_height    = (int) @imagesy($body);

$logo_width     = (int) @imagesx($logo);
$logo_height    = (int) @imagesy($logo);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($body_width + 4, $body_height + $logo_height);

imagecopy(
    $image, $logo, 
    intval($body_width / 2) - ceil($logo_width / 2), $body_height, 
    0, 0, $logo_width, $logo_height
);

imagejpeg($image, null, 85);
```

returns in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwtqZ.jpg

buuuuuuuuut...... if i add the body (the cat) to the image...

```
$body   = @imagecreatefromstring($image_data['body']);
$logo   = @imagecreatefrompng(APP_ROOT . self::WATERMARK_PATH);

$body_width     = (int) @imagesx($body);
$body_height    = (int) @imagesy($body);

$logo_width     = (int) @imagesx($logo);
$logo_height    = (int) @imagesy($logo);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($body_width + 4, $body_height + $logo_height);

imagecopy(
    $image, $body, 
    1, 1, 
    0, 0, $body_width, $body_height
);

imagecopy(
    $image, $logo, 
    intval($body_width / 2) - ceil($logo_width / 2), $body_height, 
    0, 0, $logo_width, $logo_height
);

imagejpeg($image, null, 85);
```

results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xeb73.jpg

As you can see in this last one, the bottom of the image is corrupt or something...... wtf happened?

Comment: can you show me the result without the second imagecopy()? And P.S. that many error suppressions via @, are very very very very costly, actually they might be the culprit if you didn't set_time_limit high enough o.o

Comment: it's all local execution, and takes less than a second to load.

Comment: Can I still get the result without the second imagecopy()?

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/4HxlS.jpg

Comment: I just removed the @'s.. no effect.

Comment: I'm stumped mate. The error clearly originates from before adding the watermark. might have something to do with that border thing you're trying to add :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this code I see absolutely no error:

```
<?php
$body   = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJjDi.jpg');
$logo   = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/161/161028_300.jpg');
$body_width     = (int) imagesx($body);
$body_height    = (int) imagesy($body);
$logo_width     = (int) imagesx($logo);
$logo_height    = (int) imagesy($logo);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($body_width + 4, $body_height + $logo_height);
imagecopy(
    $image, $body, 
    1, 1, 
    0, 0, $body_width, $body_height
);
imagecopy(
    $image, $logo, 
    intval($body_width / 2) - ceil($logo_width / 2), $body_height, 
    0, 0, $logo_width, $logo_height
);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image, null, 85);
?>
```

I'm gonna say it's got something to do with the actual images :-?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had left behind a header that was giving the original file size as the Content-Length... :P  `header("Content-Length: " . (string) (strlen($image_body)));`

Comment: tehee ^^ I take it the header made you realize the issue?